# Gantt tool to collaborate on with costumors without them having to sign up/create an account

Tags: planning, collaboration

I am planning a project with a customer that will span across one year.

So far, I've created a simple Gantt chart in Excel where I added timespans for tasks with shapes or text fields (see picture).

[image]

I uploaded the document to a cloud so I could work on it with my client simultaneously. Unfortunately, when oploaded, the document is opened through Excel Online, which has far fewer functions. For example, it is not possible to insert text fields there. I would have loved Excel to work as it is easy to handle and free.

Now, I am looking for a Gantt chart tool that allows me to collaborate with my costumors without them having to create an account. They sould be able to add their own tasks, timespans and comments. The application should also be easy to understand.

I've looked at Lucidchart, but it seems to work on it, an account is necessary.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! I'll try and post there, thank you for the hint!

Comment: In case you happen to use Asana, their plans also offer a Gannt view of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try TeamGantt (https://www.teamgantt.com) which allows some sharing without a log-in. Methods for sharing are here: https://support.teamgantt.com/article/89-sharing-your-project/

Answer (score 1):

You can use lots of online tools such as [Ganttpro](https://Ganttpro.com) or [Wrik project management tool](https://try.wrike.com). It can be great to add your customers as the projects' stakeholders and set permission for them.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but if anyone is still looking for something like this, check out [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/).
It has a visual Gantt chart and allows free guest users making it easy to collaborate with clients.